# Problems with manifest.json

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension for myself, however, I am having a few difficulties. **Head's up this is my first extension so I might have made a few dumb errors.

When packing my extension, chrome is giving me an error stating:

Manifest is not valid JSON.  Line: 6, column: 3, Syntax error.

Here is the code for my JSON:

```
{
  "name" : "Hello!",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "description":""
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["change.js"]
  },
  "permissions":[
  "background",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

The line that is giving problems is:

```
"background": {
```

I have also included my change.js:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @version      0.1    
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match      www.youtube.com
// @grant      none
// @run-at     document-start
// ==/UserScript==

var td = document.querySelector('tr:nth-child(1)> td:nth-child(5)'); 
td.innerText = 'Georgia';
```

Also the change.js is a user script that I wrote in tampermonkey. Does anything in the script need to be changed?

Thanks

Comment: You are missing a comma, `,` , after `"description":""` (the line prior to the one where the error is reported.

Answer (score 2):

Add a comma after `"description":""` like this:
`"description":"",`

Use a JSON validator like http://jsonlint.com/ to solve these type of JSON errors